# MVC Design - Maintaining Persistent References to Model Objects in View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

When designing iOS applications I've always followed the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern and designed view controller classes to reference classes in the model as necessary and to retain pointers only when performance or data persistence is a concern. One reason for this is to limit transient dependencies by implementing relationships between objects only when a strong dependency is required.

I'm currently designing an application whose scenes each contain a root view controller with one or more subordinate views and view controllers. This has led me to think about how pointers to at least some of the model objects should be maintained.

An alternative I've considered is to still have view controllers access models only when they are needed, but for cases where classes in the model are shared across multiple view controllers in a scene anchoring them in the root view controller for the scene. The perceived benefit of this is that it simplifies internal management of the lifecycle of the model object and it avoids a singleton, but the con is that it adds a dependency between subordinate view controllers and the root view controller. View controllers needing to reference these model objects would be required to obtain the reference through the root view controller.

I'm seeking advice and opinions from others on what pitfalls may be lurking in this type of design that I might not have thought about. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "[...] and it avoids a singleton" Is there a practical reason for avoiding a singleton?

Comment: The reason for avoiding a singleton is purely one of preference. In this case since the root view controller is already instantiated I viewed it as a natural place to anchor the reference to a model object rather than creating a separate singleton.

Comment: If a preference stands between you and an efficient, easy to understand design, changing the preference may very well be the simplest fix :-)

Comment: You adequately described the 2 alternatives, now if want to avoid too much dependency and are not fond of singleton, you may want to have a look at some Inversion of Control frameworks, like [Objection](http://objection-framework.org/). Dependency Injection could definitely be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimizing the number and duration of your objects' dependencies is a good principle to keep in mind when designing your interfaces. That should help you limit the responsibilities of each object and make them easier to test and to refactor into smaller components when needed.

Avoiding singletons also supports a well structured set of objects (single instances are of course a reality of many apps but that doesn't mean they need to be enforced or accessed using the Singleton pattern). Avoiding singletons helps avoid hidden tight coupling between classes and global state, both of which lead to classes which are hard to test, understand, and reuse.

> the con is that it adds a dependency between subordinate view controllers and the root view controller. View controllers needing to reference these model objects would be required to obtain the reference through the root view controller.

This is, I think, overlooking one important principle commonly used in designing MVC apps. Objects should have their dependencies passed to them, they should not reach out to obtain references.

If a child object requests a dependency from its parent then you have coupled those objects together. This is not necessarily unreasonable if you do so through an interface like a "data source" delegate rather than making assumptions about the class of the `parentViewController` property. Passing a data source, a factory, or a service object (like a CoreData managed object context) are all reasonable dependencies to provide to an object in place of a specific model instance.

Let your root controller construct its subordinates and pass the models (or data sources or other proxies to those models) to those subordinates. Each subordinate view controller then does not depend on being presented as a child of a particular parent and can be reused in another context much more easily.

In some cases this may mean that those view controllers retain the models they need to display for their entire life but I find that is usually not a problem. If that is expensive then it is usually easy enough to refactor the controller to depend on a factory or service which can produce the model on demand instead of on depending directly on an instance of the model.

This sort of approach can allow you to use constructor based dependency injection (passing all of an object's dependencies to its constructor [a init method in obj-c] rather than setting them via properties). Doing so allows you to enforce that an instance can only be created with all of its required dependencies available and that can help avoid confusion (rather than hoping they will be set as properties before they are needed or dealing with the consequences of changing those properties while they are in use). This doesn't always makes sense in obj-c where you might have several ways to construct an object (init vs awakeFromNib for example) but it is an option.

When this approach leads to objects accepting many dependencies just to pass them through to child objects then perhaps consider a dependency injection framework (as @Kirualex suggested in comments) to manage a central location through which dependencies can be obtained.

Comment: Thank you all for you contributions. This has been very helpful.